# Why is the type of response1 here is just object?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

```
    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Dim task = client.SendAsync(request)
        Dim response1 = Await 'task(of system.net.http.httpresponsemessage) 
        Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request) ' object?
        If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then 'this cause late binding error because response is of type object and hence doesn't support issuccessstatuscode
            '{"Success":true,"Error":null,"Data":[{"CurrencyId":2,"Symbol":"DOT","Total":9646.07411016,"Available":9646.07411016,"Unconfirmed":0.0,"HeldForTrades":0.0,"PendingWithdraw":0.0,"Address":"1HEfio1kreDBgj5uCw4VHbEDSgc6YJXfTN","Status":"OK","StatusMessage":null}]}
            Console.WriteLine(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
        End If
    End Using
```

I wonder why.

I think type of response and response1 should be

system.net.http.httpresponsemessage

Why it's just object?

I thought await operator would take out turn `task(of something)` into `something`.

On top I got

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
```

Here is a screenshot where the hover tips say that type of response1 is object

[image]

Here is a screenshot the visual studio complaining about late binding because type of response1 is object

[image]

Here is a screenshot that I do not have system.thread assembly available. In fact, only one assembly starts with system.t... is system transactions

[image]

Comment: I just pasted your code into a new Console project and Intellisense indicates that both `response` and `response1` are type `HttpResponseMessage`, as you'd expect. The only reason that I can see that they wouldn't be is that you have `Option Infer` and `Option Strict` both `Off`, but then you'd have no issue with late-binding.  I think that your project may be broken.  I'd suggest trying a new test project to se whether it behaves the same way.

Comment: Maybe I had wrong visual studio edition? I did get compile error on both. No option infer and option strict should be on. Let me check again

Comment: There see the screenshot?

Comment: Look at the last error message visible in your second screenshot.  That seems relevant to your issue.  My guess would be that your project does not have access to the `Task` class.

Comment: I just did a bit of testing and the `Task` class is accessible from mscorlib.dll in .NET 4.5 and later but requires a reference to System.Threading.Tasks.dll in .NET 4.0.  If you're targeting .NET 4.0 then that would be the issue but I'm not sure how that can be the case, because `HttpRequestMessage` requires at least .NET 4.5.  I'm confused.

Comment: You should turn this into answer

Comment: I didn't know that it was an answer. What was the final solution?

Comment: How do I know which .net I am targetting? There is no system.threading.tasks

Comment: I retarget the project to aim for .net 4.5. I didn't know these things. Sorry

Comment: Are you saying that it was previously targeting .NET 4.0 and you've updated that to 4.5? If so then, as I said, I'm still confused because, according to the documentation, the `HttpRequestMessage` type that you were already using wasn't available before .NET 4.5.

Comment: Please turn that into anwer and I will mark that. That is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue was that the project was targeting .NET 4.0, in which case the `Task` and `Task(Of T)` types are not accessible without a reference to System.Threading.Tasks.dll.  .NET 4.5 and later declare those types in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: He he I just want to show a bit of appreciation for your help. Won't be able to figure this out without you.

Comment: Appreciate the appreciation.